# How to get substrings from a string based on some character in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string like `962=962&961=961&485=485`

I want to save the values into an array.

I may be asking a silly question, but I got stuck here.

Thanks

Comment: what do you want the array to look like? `[962,961,485]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the values, you can pass a regular expression to [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
>>> "962=962&961=961&485=485".split(/[=&]/)
["962", "962", "961", "961", "485", "485"]
```

Comment: to remove the duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want only values after the = sign.
i.e. array like this [962,961,485]

Comment: @user, the most efficient solutions can be found in the duplicate, then :)

Comment: I removed the duplicates by using the below code
$.each(id, function(i, el){
  if($.inArray(el, uniqueId) === -1) {
    uniqueId.push(el);
  }
});